# Why is $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty f(x) \,dx+ \frac{f(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2} \, dx $ true?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have found a method of integration on this website: https://brilliant.org/wiki/integration-tricks/

But I'm not sure how the U-sub offered in the article gets to the conclusion it states. I'm not too sure where to start. My knowledge of U-sub didn't seem to work with achieving their answer.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have \begin{align*}\int_0^{\infty} f(x) &= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\ & = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x \\ & = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} f(x) + \frac{1}{x^2}f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x\end{align*}

where we use $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ on the second term of the first equality.

Comment: All too easy!  (+1)

Comment: Holy moly that's beautiful thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(1/x)}{x^2}\,dx$$
By taking $x\to 1/x$, we have
$$=\int_\infty^0 x^2f(x)\cdot -\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$$
$$=-\int_\infty^0 f(x)\,dx$$
$$=\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$$
and so
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(1/x)}{x^2}\,dx=\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$$
and your result follows directly from this.